# protecting questions

Tags: discussion

We've seen questions being protected in the past (sometimes when TS spammed them) to prevent new users from posting superfluous answers. Protected questions require 10 rep to answer.

Wouldn't it be a good idea if certain questions get protected automatically? Like for instance when there are already 5 answers and there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In principle I'd say no, even a newbie might add value to already answered questions, and they have a sort of "natural" protection given by upvotes. Poor content will stay in the bottom and won't harm the good one.

But this is more appropriate for the main [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as it affects the whole network.

Comment: I noticed a while back that my question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55368/triac-snubber-design-for-multi-purpose-switching had been locked by community. I remember it was bumped a few times by what I think must have been deleted answers that I didn't see so I thought something like this must have been in place. I thought a person protecting a question would always show their name?

Comment: @PeterJ not necessarily: some moderation tools (like closing or deleting) are associated to the moderator who performed the actions, some others aren't. It's also something about the engine, probably there is something about this on Meta. On a side note, perhaps it would be appropriate to rephrase the title of that question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the edit. I'd shared that question on a fairly high-traffic site so while (hopefully) it attracted a few good new users I wasn't suprised it would have got a few responses from people not familiar with SE.

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, I just thought that maybe people would expect it to answer all their questions, maybe it should be less of a problem (and of course it's protected, too)